# How can I add in new Locales to the locale list?

Tags: localization

I have a site that has a few different countries that speak the same language but want to have them as different Locales.

- Mexico (english)
- Mexico (spanish)
- USA (english)
- USA (spanish)
- Peru (english)
- Peru (spanish)

These might all share some content but the manager of each region might want to change the content for their own region.

How can I add in new Locales in the locale list in Craft?

Comment: Andrew, see Brad's answer to this question here: ["Can I change the list of available locales?"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1054/125).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several locales that Yii comes with but Craft doesn't, simply to keep Craft's filesize down a bit (they add a lot of weight). You can see the master list of Yii locales here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/tree/master/framework/i18n/data   - If you see a locale in there you want that Craft doesn't come with, just view the raw version of the file on GitHub and then save it to your craft/app/framework/i18n/data/ folder. Then Craft will start supporting it.

If you need a locale that Yii *doesn’t* offer, find the closest locale Yii/Craft does come with, and copy it with a new name (e.g. `en_us.php` => `en_mx.php`).

Comment: Is this safe for when the system updates? I am just thinking there should be a top level directory not so deep rooted into the framework to do this.

Comment: It should be safe, yeah. We will be making this process easier in the future for sure, but this is how you can do it today :)